# Trying to use mockito with Arquillian but having some problems

Tags: mockito, junit4, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-9

I was tring to use mockito with arquillian.
I used with simple JUnit and it runs fine although i am trying to figure out the deployment for arquillian which is where i think the problem is !!!
Can anyone help me to figure out ?

Thank you.

Here is the link to my junit file and pom file

Comment: Adding your test class would be good. My guess is you're not including the mockito jars into your microdeployment.

Comment: yes that was the problem...its resolved now. Thanks

Comment: Added my comment as an answer.

Comment: still cannot up the points because i dont have enough reputation points still...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using external libraries in your tests, you must make sure those libraries have been added to the microdeployment.